# question about javascript function references

Tags: javascript, function, reference, scope

Why doesn't this code:

```
<a href="#">Sample link</a>
<script>
    setTimeout($('a').hide, 2000)
</script>
```

work like this one:

```
<a href="#">Sample link</a>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ $('a').hide(); }, 2000)
</script>
```

Comment: @SLaks @Andrea both great answers but IMO Andrea's takes the lead with that link, plus he has a lower score. Wish I could tick both though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `this` is bound to the global object inside setTimeout calls. It follows that both

```
setTimeout($('a').hide, 2000)
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('a').hide(); }, 2000)
```

will call the methos `$('a').hide`, but with different values for `this` (`window` in the first case and `$('a')` in the second).

[Here](http://seanmonstar.com/post/707068021/4-ways-functions-mess-with-this) are more details about the value of `this` according to the way you invoke a function.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `$('a').hide` returns jQuery's standard `hide` function, without any reference to `$('a')`.
When you *call* `$('a').hide()` as a statement, `$('a')` is passed as the `this` parameter to `hide`.

However, when you pass the `hide` function to `setTimeout`, it doesn't call the function on `$('a')`; all `setTimeout`'d functions are called on `window`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `this`. In JavaScript it's the dot notation used while calling the function that binds `this` -- so while in you first example you are passing *a* hide function, it's not connected to any particular jQuery object.

Answer (score -2):

And if you want that your line of code work, you should quote it:

```
setTimeout("$('a').hide()", 2000)
OR
```

Have a look to : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I'm assuming this uses eval in the back-end or...?